# SQL Query inner join in Linq

Tags: linq

```
SELECT  
    EmployeeType.EmployeeTypeName, EmployeeAttendanceTypes.OverTimeAllowed, 
    EmployeeAttendanceTypes.SundayOffAllowed,                 
    EmployeeAttendanceTypes.LeavesAllowed
FROM
    EmployeeAttendanceTypes 
INNER JOIN
    EmployeeType ON EmployeeAttendanceTypes.CompanyId = EmployeeType.CompanyId 
                 AND EmployeeAttendanceTypes.EmployeeTypeId = EmployeeType.EmployeeTypeId
```

How to write this query in Linq for C# ?

Comment: You don't, at least in well designed solutions. You create relations in your entities so that eg. EmployeeType has an AttendanceTypes collection property. After that, loading a single EmployeeType will also load the relevant AttendanceTypes, either eagerly (ie with joins) or lazily (with separate queries if/when you require them)

Comment: Another option is to define this as a M-1 relation, ie if EmployeeType can have only one AttendanceType, the EmployeeType class will have a single AttendanceType property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree with the comment that you don't but it's not always possible to avoid. Try:

```
var result = from eat in EmployeeAttaendanceType
             join et in EmployeeType on 
                 new { cId = eat.CompanyId, etId = eat.EmployeeTypeId } 
             equals 
                 new { cId = et.CompanyId, etId = et.EmployeeTypeId }
             select new {
                 EmployeeTypeName = EmployeeType.EmployeeTypeName, 
                 OverTimeAllowed = EmployeeAttendanceTypes.OverTimeAllowed,     
                 SundayOffAllowed = EmployeeAttendanceTypes.SundayOffAllowed,                 
                 LeavesAllowed = EmployeeAttendanceTypes.LeavesAllowed
             }
```

Or you can do this

```
var result = EmployeeAttendanceType.Join(EmployeeType,
               eat => new { cId = eat.CompanyId, etId = eat.EmployeeTypeId },        
               et => new { cId = et.CompanyId, etId = et.EmployeeTypeId },
               (eat, et) => new {
                   EmployeeTypeName = EmployeeType.EmployeeTypeName, 
                   OverTimeAllowed = EmployeeAttendanceTypes.OverTimeAllowed,     
                   SundayOffAllowed = EmployeeAttendanceTypes.SundayOffAllowed,                 
                   LeavesAllowed = EmployeeAttendanceTypes.LeavesAllowed
               });
```

These select into anonymous types but can select into any object.